# PostgreSQL If else

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I have issue. I try to do one If-Else, In postgresql.
I have 2 colums. "measure" is the measurements INT,  and the another column is the "Status" boolean. Both on different table. The query simple, If the measurement more than 100 then change the "Status_SG" true.
I lerned Sql but not this deep, and now I stuck.

Checked online many option but non of them works.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL. You are most probably looking for a [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Check the manual, in SQL (also PostgreSQL) you need a CASE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can solve the problem .

```
    SELECT 
CASE WHEN (a.intcol > 100) AND b.booleancol THEN 'message1' ELSE 'message2' END
FROM table AS a 
JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Note that `CASE WHEN a.intcolumn > 100 THEN true ELSE false END` can be simplified to `a.intcolumn > 100`

Comment: good sight @a_horse_with_no_name , i edited the post to add the easier solution